# Creating multiple columns for last user edit ArcGIS Portal

Tags: editing, arcgis-portal, arcgis-enterprise

I enabled editing and tracking on the ArcGIS Enterprise Portal. But for this project my manager is asking to store the editing data (username and time stamp) of multiple users (not just the last user).

Can this be done, either on a hosted layer on the portal or a feature layer in a registered database?

She also suggested that instead of making an additional column each time a user edits, we could make a duplicate record.

Comment: You could add a trigger function in SQL cliffpatterson.ca/blog/2017/10/29/postgresqlpostgis-trigger-functions/ and https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/history_tracking.html where they are describing something similar to what you might be trying to do. It's relatively simple to add the modified information to a table as the data is being edited but the real problem is how are you going to make any sense from the collected data? You could summarize the table directly to see how many edits a user makes in a day but tracking the edit lineage for a single feature that would be difficult.

Comment: Do some readup on Geodatabase Archiving and historical moments.  Both can work with ArcGIS Enterprise workflows.  http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/petrol17/papers/petrol_31.pdf